# Bitvise SSH error after windows 10 1803 update

Tags: windows, ssh

I got the 1803 update yesterday and realized today that I got an error on Bitvise SSH.
I have multiple VPS, I get the same error.

This the error message I received:

> The SSH2 session has terminated with error. Reason: Error in component
>   session/transport/kexHandler. Error class: Flow, code:
>   ComponentException, message: Exception in component: Windows CNG (x86)
>   with additions: AsymKey: CngAgree: unexpected secretData->cbStruct.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I fixed this by upgrading my Bitvise SSH client from 7.27 to version 7.41.

Comment: Can confirm Windows has been doing a lot of network stuff, upgrading Windows and installing new BitVise fixes the issue. Also my WiFi was SLOW. Now it's great.

Answer (score 9):

Updating to [the latest version of Bitvise SSH Client](https://dl.bitvise.com/BvSshClient-Inst.exe) helped me fixed this issue.

(from version 7.39 to 7.45)

Answer (score 5):

i solved this issue by upgrading to latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by running bitvise in windows 7 compatibility mode

Comment: I'm running windows 7 as well. Since upgrading to newer bitvise version solves the problem, I think it would be better to upgrade the software which may have help fix several other bugs and patches in the old version as well. I used version 7.24, which generated the same error as described in the question.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am doing -- stay in Windows 7.